# A ball of mass 22g moves to the left at a speed of 35 m / s

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, work

A ball of mass 22g moves to the left at a speed of 35 m / s. How much work needs to be done on the ball to start moving to the right at a speed of 35 m / s. When considering ignore any energy losses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the work-energy theorem. The work-energy theorem says that the work done on a body by external forces on it is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the body. Recall that kinetic energy depends on the speed, and not the velocity. Keeping this in mind, what do you think the change in kinetic energy will be? Whatever value you get for the change in kinetic energy, will be the amount of work done.

Comment: There is no change in energy, ie the change in energy is 0J, so the work is equal to zero.

Comment: And that is the correct answer.

Comment: Reply to Deleted comment :No it doesn't require speed is constant, the net work is zero in either case. Key word being NET

Comment: @jensenpaull I’m sorry, I don’t quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Heisenberg I made a stupid comment that I deleted!

Comment: @jensenpaull oh sorry I didn’t realise you replied to a deleted comment.

Comment: @Robbie happens to the best of us

Comment: It goes against our intuition that no work is being done on the object, since for US apply a force to an object, we need to use energy. But at the most fundamental level, when an object has a decrease in kinetic energy, energy is added to the field, and then when it accelerates in the opposite direction and speed up, the energy is taken away from the field. Such that the amount of work done by the field on the object is zero